# Is a language of TMs undecidable using Rice's theorem

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Given a language:
$A = \{ <M> | M\ rejects\ the\ string\ "101" \}$

Can I prove it is undecidable using Rice's theorem?

See like the theorem conditions are met (there exists non trivial language that describes the machine language )

Comment: Do you mean "undecidable"? (Rice's theorem shows undecidability, not decidability).

Comment: Yes - fixed now.

Comment: So, if you think the conditions are met - what's the question?

Comment: I know that you cannot apply rice theorem when a machine constrain is set (in this case , the machine must reject) is it true? Is the proof ok?

Comment: Just check whether or not the conditions of Rice's theorem hold. There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Rice's theorem says that any nontrivial *semantic* property of TMs is undecidable.
The property in question is clearly nontrivial, but let's see if it's semantic.

A semantic property of TMs is a set of TMs $P$ such that for every two TMs $M_1,M_2$, if $L(M_1)=L(M_2)$ then either $M_1,M_2\in P$ or $M_1,M_2\notin P$. That is, membership in $P$ is determined only by the language, and not by the "inner workings" of the machine.

In this case, since "rejecting" and "never halting" are the same thing from the point of view of the language, then the property is **not** semantic. That is, there can be two machines with the same language, where one rejects 101, and the other doesn't halt on 101.

So no, you can't use Rice's theorem here.

Comment: The word *semantic* should be replaced with the word *extensional*.

Comment: @AndrejBauer - why? Semantic properties are a very standard term for this. Also, they really are semantic, as they refer to the language, rather than the specific structure.

Comment: By calling extensional properties semantic you are implicitly stating that the meaning of a Turing machine is its extensional behavior (i.e., what outputs it yields on various inputs). But I beg to differ. The natural semantics of a Turing machine is its *operational behavior*, i.e, it is important *how* Turing machines calculate outputs.

If you use the word *extensional* then there is no question about what semantics of Turing machines you might have in mind. It is clear that we are talking about the extensional behavior of machines, i.e., what outputs they produce on given inputs.

Comment: It's an interesting discussion, probably the wrong place for it. Anyway, IMO the semantics is indeed the output. If you want to "see" the operational behaviour, then work with transducers that output the name of the current state, for example. Indeed, if you take two different TMs, you cannot compare them based on their behaviour, since their structures may be completely different (e.g. have different state names). The fact that TMs actually have accept/reject states is so that there is a "meaning" to the computation, which is not the computation itself.